# Excel VBA list files from a URL

Tags: url, vba, excel

Ok, how would I hist all the files in a folder that is located on a remote server that I have to access using a URL e.g. http://domain.com/folder and inside the folder there are a bunch of files that I would like listing into excel. There are functions do this when trying to list files in a folder that are on your current C:\ but they don't work when trying to list files from a URL. I am not sure if this can be done! Thanks

Comment: Can you access the site via `FTP`? If not you are left with querying the `html's DOM` with `xPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Map the server directory as a local drive on your machine (e.g. O:) and use a small VBA procedure, e.g.

```
Sub ServerDir()
Dim Idx As Integer, FN As String, R As Range

    Set R = Selection
    Idx = 1
    ' URL =  http://repository.XXXXX.com/content/dav/Repository/Users/Users-M/mike.d/mike.d-Public/
    ' mapped http://repository.XXXXX.com/content/dav/ to O:\ 
    FN = Dir("O:\Repository\Users\Users-M\mike.d\mike.d-Public\*.ppt")

    Do While FN <> ""
        R(Idx, 1) = FN
        FN = Dir()
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```